# cannot get xp_seller and bcp to play nice with stored procedure with parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, bcp

I am trying to get an XML file out from my stored procedure using xp_cmdshell and bcp. The example of a BCP statement work... I get a file... So, knowing that works, and the stored procedure works, I cannot get them to work together.

-- This works:  
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT * FROM sysfiles" queryout "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\table.xml" -T -c -t,'

-- This works:  
EXEC pn_FlatProductXML "KA-0009"

I'm getting tripped up in the single and double quotes, etc... Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, note the pair of single-quotes around the stored procedure parameter:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "EXEC DatabaseName.dbo.pn_FlatProductXML ''KA-0009'' " queryout "C:\test.txt" -T -c '
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! The only thing that didn't was the C:\. There is some security reason that I cannot write to that directory... only the 'backup' directory.